# What application and codec can I use to encode raw HD video from Fraps?

Tags: h.264, video-encoding, video-codecs

I have large (4 GB each) HD video files (.avi) recorded using Fraps.

What application and codec (freeware) can I use to encode these videos and make them smaller?

I'd like my videos to be watchable on Windows, Linux, Mac OS X and possibly in browsers with HTML5 support.

I've already made a search and found out that h.264 should be OK. But I can't figure out how to encode my videos using it. I've found [x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) project and [x264 unofficial binary](http://x264.nl/). But it seems to be a command line utility which is hard to use.

Added: My OS is Windows XP or 7, but crossplatfrom solution would be preffered.

Comment: So we know what Os you want it to work for, but what OS are you on or prefer  to do the encoding?  I disagree that 264 is ok, there are many devices and computers not yet set up for that. Some older small devices (like our gpses) cant use that codec although they can easily use the standard Xvid and divx and MSes MP4 codecs, it would just depend on what software they have and use and what they will install. Check this, whatever you use see if it will work in a Stock MS xp and win7 and stock Mac and stock Iphone and ipad, without a single change, using built in players.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is your favorite transcoding software?](http://superuser.com/questions/9819/what-is-your-favorite-transcoding-software)

Comment: Lame duplicate, but just try a few applications suggested there! See also, our blog entry: [Video Conversion done right: Codecs and Software - Super User Blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/11/07/video-conversion-done-right-codecs-and-software/)

Comment: @Psycogeek, I've added OS

Comment: What codec will you suggest? VP8 also seems to be good. @slhck, thanks for your links, I'll read and try.

Comment: I am an old fan of virtual dub. I must have filters, must be able to control things as needed, and must do a 2 pass. I prefer xvid mp4 as balance of good vrses compatable (and set for a divx header for "more" compatable).  temporal filter is an interesting item to apply when compressing, it can be nice to increase sharpness and color a bit when displaying smaller, and precise bicubic is my fav downsize alogrythm. Check it out, but there are things to learn with that.  SLHCKs blog post is Very well done and thought up. All that is very good today info.

Comment: Depends on your application afterwards — x264 will offer better compression and quality, but it takes longer to encode and might be troublesome for legacy devices. Xvid is easier to encode but results in larger files, yet slightly better compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codec: h.264 or VP8/VP9

Software: XMedia Recode, Handbrake

I've taken bitrates from youtube guide and used 2 Pass Average Bitrate setting for maximum quality

Answer (score 0):

See if [MeGui](https://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/) will be a good solution for you. I've used it like forever, though it is somewhat geeky.

> **Description**
>
> MeGUI is the most comprehensive GUI based ISO MPEG-4 solution. It suports MPEG-4 ASP (xvid), MPEG-4 AVC (x264), AAC, MP2, MP3, Flac, Vorbis, AC3 audio and various common containers support (MP4, MKV, AVI, M2TS).

It's completely free, though. Codec: x264 in this case. If you choose MP4 as your [container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats), Windows 7 should be able to decode it out of the box, XP probably needs some player, like MPC-HC. MAC of cource decodes it too.